# как копировать объект с массива

Tags: c#, объекты, copy

```
     Element tree = new Element { Name = "tree", Hp = 2 };

     Element templayte = tree;

        tree.Name = "asd";
        WriteLine(templayte.Name);
```

у меня копирует ссылку на объект не сам объект

Comment: `Element templayte  = new Element { Name = tree.Name , Hp = tree.Hp  };`?

Comment: спасибо большое , помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

так как `Element` - ссылочный тип, то эта конструкция `Element templayte = tree;` не создаст копию объекта. Копию вам придется создавать самому

```
Element templayte = new Element { Name = tree.Name , Hp = tree.Hp };
```